# how to support of all screen size android

Tags: android

iwant to ask that how to support for all screen size mobile in android
means if i have created a xml layout and i want display same layout on diffrent-2 screen then what to do for that means i had tested my application in small screen and also in big screen but in big screen it looking good but in small layout content out side od view means not visible which is below ,so whats the solution for this?

Comment: pls refer to my qus part ...i had post my layout  filter.xml

Comment: is the **artspaces** text view visible in small screens? it has for example 160dip left margin. how small is your small screen. else you may need to create a layout-ldpi folder and have an another version of this file.

Comment: ya art spaces text is visible properly but problem in vertical alignment means 4th spinner and button  at bottom is not visible..

Comment: cant you just put the whole layout in a scrollview. does your webview has a scroll. android cannot nest scrolling though.

Comment: hi  Sam Quest i put scrollview now via scrolling i can see all widgets.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if vertical space is only your issue.

cant you just put the whole layout in a scrollview. does your webview has a scroll.

android cannot nest scrolling though.